# If we set browser caching for a JS or CSS file via .htaccess what happens if we need to push a fix ASAP?

Tags: .htaccess, caching

If we set browser caching for a JS or CSS file via .htaccess what happens if we need to push a fix ASAP ?

Eg. By accident we push a bug that stops the site functioning, say we set the whole body to `display:none;` in the css.

The site in question is a static html / js / css site running on a lamp stack

If we had 2 days browser caching enabled, and someone visited the site whilst the bug was up, is there a way to purge all caches (without renaming the file) in such an incident ?

Comment: Add a GET parameter, like `stylesheet.css?something=20160516`

Comment: Thanks for the input @Pekka웃 the sites actually a static site - with that being the case would a GET param work ?

Comment: Yes. It's just to make the browser think it's accessing a different URL, so it forgets all caching instructions. It's the only bulletproof way, AFAIK

Comment: @sam - Just so you know, this is generally known as cache-busting. In this particular case (the suggesstion made by Pekka), it is known (somewhat uncommonly, I might add) as URL Fingerprinting.